# Is it possible to use variables in a PDF document?

Tags: pdf

I want to make a editable PDF document – but I want to take it a step further.

Is it possible to create some editable fields on the first page where the user can put in personal information (name, age etc.) and have the document fill itself in where "name" is required?

I need this for some employment contracts and it would be alot faster if the user only needs to fill the information in once, print the PDF and sign it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PDF a single form field may have multiple widgets. By definition all these widgets have the same content.

E.g. have a look at thie sample document [aFieldTwice.pdf](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/resources/mkl/testarea/itext5/form/aFieldTwice.pdf?raw=true). You see two fields. As soon as you edit one of them and press enter, the same content occurs in the other one.

This might be what you look for.

Comment: I expect that to also work across pages. I created the puff using iText and Java.